# CGI::Session Randomly clearing parameter

Tags: perl, session, cookies, cgi

When users log in I have created a new Session in Perl CGI, and stored the session ID in a cookie (CGISESSID). This cookie has then been sent the next page via a redirect, as shown below:

```
my $session = CGI::Session->new("driver:File", undef, {Directory=>"/tmp"});
my $sid = $session->id();
$session->param("username", $username);
$session->expire('+15m');
print redirect ( -cookie => cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id), -uri => 'x.cgi');
```

On 'x.cgi' (and all other pages of the site) I have:

```
my $sid = cookie ('CGISESSID') || param('CGISESSID') || undef;
my $session = CGI::Session->load(undef, $sid, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
$session->expire('+15m');
my $username = $session->param("username");
if (!defined ($username)) {
    print redirect ("login.cgi");
}
```

However, after a random amount of time/clicks (well before the 15m mark, anywhere from the 1st click to a click 2-3 minutes later), it redirects to login.cgi.

Debugging has shown me that although it redirects me (and $username is not defined), the code still obtains the correct session ID originally created (the session seems to be still intact), and the cookie remains.

I don't pass CGISESSID as a parameter on any page requests/links (as I assume a cookie saves me from doing this)

Any idea what could be causing $username to be undefined after a random amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your description is correct and your code works for some time, and after that stops working, I would suggest checking that noone is cleaning up your `/tmp` directory and, in particular, the session file there.

When you create a session using `CGI::Session` module with `file` driver it just creates a text file in the given directory (`/tmp` in your code). It's a text file with some Perl code, you can `cat` it and see what's inside:

```
$ cat cgisess_126b3cd2c4b9ac6eaac0185afbc46d34 && echo
$D = {'_SESSION_ID' => '126b3cd2c4b9ac6eaac0185afbc46d34','_SESSION_ATIME' => 1413493418,'_SESSION_REMOTE_ADDR' => '','_SESSION_CTIME' => 1413493418};;$D
```

For `file` driver the filename it uses for the session can be obtained by

```
my $filename = sprintf $CGI::Session::Driver::file::FileName, $session->id;
```

Check that it is created and exists for at least 15 minutes. If it disappears, blame some cron job, some other script or your hosting provider.

Comment: Changed the directory and it seems to be working for now. Thanks :)